# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager' while attempting to activate 'WebShop.Controllers.User.UserController'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Im new at Entity-framework. 
And im working on a webapplication, I want to make a userauthentication modul to an Angular site.
User login work perfectly.When i try to add user roles i got the following error message:

And I got the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf2oz.png)

I using JWT token for authenticator. 
And Microsoft.IdentityModel.

My code:
Startup.cs
Identity service:

```
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebShopContext>();
```

JWT aut service:

```
 var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"]);

        services.AddAuthentication(x => 
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x=> {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = false;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero 
            };
        });
    }
```

My ApplicationRole model:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My ApplicationUser model:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Column(TypeName="nvarchar(150)")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

I have absolutly no idea. How can I solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: What version of .Net Core are you using?

Comment: .Net core version 2.2 
Entity framework core version 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```cs
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebShopContext>();
```

to

```cs
      services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>() // <--- changed to ApplicationUser
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebShopContext>();
```

I'm going to assume, from reading the error, your model that inherits from `IdentityUser` is `ApplicationUser` and you're setting up your service to look for an `IdentityUser` and not an `ApplicationUser` which is what you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah, it's work thank you.
But now i read empty arrays out from database, but in database there are rows.

Comment: Great, if you could mark the answer I would love that.

Comment: Also, if you're getting a null reference error, maybe you don't have anything in your db? Or you're searching for the wrong parameter when you're trying to find the User? Just general things to look for.

Comment: I made a stupid error :D 
Now everything is work fine. Thanks you again.

Comment: In my database the datarows discriminator values were different than the name of the RoleManager class ("ApplicationRole") and it don't care about that rows. 
Now I change the Discriminator values in the Database to "ApplicationRole" and everything work perfectly, I see each record.